# How to relevant data get from PHP api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, urlencode

I need to append params to my query, but I always get different results. I tried a few ways but without success. Check code below.

First check my code which work without new URL (I need to use `new URL`).

```js
let url = `${getBaseUrl()}/myUrl/search?surnames=${allData.join('%0A')}`
```

This works well, but when I use `new URL`:

```js
let url = new URL('myUrl/search' , getBaseUrl())
url.searchParams.append('surnames' , allData);
```

The code above doesn't work, and I don't know the reason why?

I tried to inspect url and see different

- Works: `search?surnames=smith%0Ajordan`
- Doesn't work: `search?surnames=smith%250Ajordan`

The only difference is inside between "smith" and "jordan"

- With `%0A` work
- With `%250A` doesn't work

Not sure how this was generated.

Answer (score 1):

The original `%` is being encoded as `%25`, so `%0` becomes `%250`.

Try using an unencoded line feed (`\n`):

```js
const
  allData = ['smith', 'jordan'],
  getBaseUrl = () => 'https://localhost:8080',
  url = new URL('myUrl/search' , getBaseUrl());

url.searchParams.append('surnames', allData.join('\n'));

console.log(url); // https://localhost:8080/myUrl/search?surnames=smith%0Ajordan
```